# Convert idiosyncratically formatted .txt file to XML

Tags: xml

I have several large plain text files which are 'glossaries' for personal use made during my PhD. They are uselessly formatted like so:

```
%%% <entry i>

    Blah Blah Blah, see also > <entry j>


%%% <entry i+1>
```

etc. (Note the cross-reference.)

In their present state these files cannot easily be *used* (e.g. for creating display versions with LaTeX, or for putting a subset of entries on a website); they can essentially only be *browsed* in a text editor. It seem converting everything to XML might be the best way to increase flexibility and usability, so what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Which scripting language do you know, like or are you bent on learning?

Comment: Bash for simple things (so probably this), and Python for longer things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be the basis of such a converter in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import fileinput
import re

entryre = re.compile( "^%%% <([^>]+)>")
seealsore = re.compile( "see also > <([^>]+)>")

def pnode(nodename, nodeblock):
    print "<" + nodename + ">"
    print nodeblock
    print "</" + nodename + ">"


block = ""
entry = ""
for line in fileinput.input():
    match = re.match( entryre, line)
    if match:
        if entry:
            pnode(entry, block)
            block = ""
            entry = ""
        entry = match.group(1)
    else:
        match = re.match( seealsore, line)
        line = re.sub( seealsore, r'<seealso>\1</seealso>', line)
        block += line

pnode(entry, block)
```

It reads any file (stdin is suggested) and writes stdout. Just wrap the output between an xml head and tail.
If the entries contain white spaces, that should be taken care. Also, if the blocks contain tag-like ("") substrings, additional conversion is needed.

However, if you wish just to browse the entries, I suggest using simple html. Definition lists or tables would both serve you well.
The conversion code would require only small changes.